# Teamcity overview, not showing build history

Tags: c#, svn, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I've just created a new build in my project, all my builds always used to have build history, but this build configuration doesn't show in the overview tabs even though there is sucessful build.

It's not a big issue but still annoying.

The only difference with this build is it doesn't have any special trigger as I trigger it manually and it prompt for 2 special parameters.

I'm using teamcity 7.0 on HSQL soonly MYSQL.

Seee screenshot.

[image]

Comment: When you trigger it, are you running it as a private build?

Comment: No and all builds are visible when I go on the details on the build. Just the overview doesn't show them

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to latest Team city version (7.0.3). Similar problems were fixed there.

Comment: Do you use parameter references in VCS root settings?